# Azure API Management - Defining Custom Error

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm using Azure API management for my project, with a backend service provided by Fiorano ESB. Fiorano to Azure has a peer-to-peer connectivity. 
The services is deployed in the peer server which is added as a cloud service in azure. 
So my concern is : for an API, in the URL if the resource is missing or wrong by default we'll get a json response as

```
{
    "stausCode" : 404,
    "message" : "Resource not found"
}
```

Is there any way that I can define this in OData standard format i.e. can i define it in a custom format as given below:

```
{
    "error":{  
    "code" : "404_RES",                                                                                                   
    "message":{                                                                                                                        
        "lang":"en-uk",                                                                                                             
        "value":"Resource $(wrong_resource given) is not found"                                                                              
     },                                                                                                                    
    "innererror":{ 
  "trace":[],                                                                                                               
    "context":{}    
     }                                                                                                         
     }
 }
```

The $(wrong resource) should be taken dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at set-body policy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894083.aspx#SetBody. 
Basically, it allows you to modify/replace message bodies of incoming and outgoing requests.